# What is $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{j+1}{2^j}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

What is $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{j+1}{2^j}$?

I don't know what theorems or tricks to use to add up an infinite sum.

Comment: As you see in the answers below, by writing this as $\Sigma_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{j}{2^j} + \Sigma_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^j}$, you now have an  arcane way of writing $2 + 2 = 4$. :p

Answer (score 1):

Start with:
$$
\sum_{j \ge 0} z^j = \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Derive with respect to $z$, and evaluate at $z = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you know the sum formula for an infinite geometric series, so that you can find  $\Sigma_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1^j}{2^j}.$

The other part of the infinite sum is  $\Sigma_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{j}{2^j}.$  Make a triangular stack of infinite series like this:

$$
\begin{array}{r}
& \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}  + \ldots \\
&               \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}  + \ldots \\
&                             \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}  + \ldots \\
&                                           \frac{1}{16}  + \ldots \\
&           \ldots
\end{array}
$$
so that all the identical terms form columns.  Summed vertically, they are the terms of your series $\Sigma_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{j}{2^j}.$ [Note that $j = 0 $ produces *no* terms here.] Horizontally, each row is an infinite geometric series with ratio $r = \frac{1}{2}$ and a different initial term.  There will be a reasonable expression for the sum of the infinitude of these geometric series.  Now add that result to your earlier value for  $\Sigma_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1^j}{2^j}.$

Comment: Thanks for better aligning my columns!

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j+1}{2^j}$ and consider $1/2 S = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j+1}{2^{j+1}}.$ Note then that $S - 1/2 S = 1 +\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{j+1}} = 2,$ whence $S = 4.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$T_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{j+1}{2^j} \,,$$

Then

$$2T_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{j+1}{2^{j-1}}=\sum_{m=-1}^{n-1}\frac{m+2}{2^m}$$
$$2T_n= 2+\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{m+2}{2^m}= 2-\frac{n+1}{2^n}+\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{m+2}{2^m}$$
$$2T_n= 2-\frac{n+1}{2^n}+\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{m+1}{2^m}+\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^m}$$
$$2T_n= 2-\frac{n+1}{2^n}+T_n+(2-\frac{1}{2^n+1})$$

Thus

$$T_n= 4-\frac{n+1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^n+1} \,.$$

It is easy now to calculate $\lim_n T_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's split it into two series:

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{j}{2^j} + \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}$.

The second series is a geometric series and I'm sure you know how to evaluate it (if not, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)). The first series is a little trickier and requires some calculus. Let's define the following series (or function, however you wish to look at it):

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^j$.

What happens if we differentiate this function? Is there a specific value of $x$ that can relate this new expression to your initial sum?